# Vb.net sum identical array elements

Tags: vb.net

I have an array with elements 10,11,11,11,17,17,20.

I want to add elements which are the same (ie. 11 and 17), so that the array now has elements 10,33,34,20.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var arr = new[]{ 10,11,11,11,17,17,20 };
arr = arr.GroupBy (x => x).Select (x => x.Sum()).ToArray();
```

Comment: It is almost the same. `arr.GroupBy(Function(x) x).Select(Function(x) x.Sum()).ToArray()`